# Unable to create EC2 Key Pair through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-keypair.html

Based on this documentation, you should be able to create a new key pair when launching an instance instead of creating one before hand and referencing it through parameters.

AWS even provides an example:

```
Resources:
  NewKeyPair:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair'
    Properties:
      KeyName: MyKeyPair
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-02b92c281a4d3dc79
      KeyName: !Ref NewKeyPair
```

The template is valid, but after I launch the stack I get this error:

**NewKeyPair - Resource handler returned message: "null" (RequestToken: 6068026b-63b2-c71b-6cbb-f76f09fe599e, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)**

**EC2-SecurityKey   - The following resource(s) failed to create: [NewKeyPair]. Rollback requested by user.**

Anyone know why this rollback occurs and if I am missing something?

Comment: Do you already have a keypair named "NewKeyPair"? "AlreadyExists" in the error indicates the name may not be unique.

Comment: If in your case, the error message has `HandlerErrorCode: InternalFailure`, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77936671/12326605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Your Keypairs from the ec2 console this error is about you already created "MyKeyPair" named key that's why this error is coming. If you want to create a key pair change a keypair name in this script or delete the old key pair named "MyKeyPair". This might be solve this error

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped. Do you think creating a keypair through CF is a waste though? Unlike creating it through the console, it does not give me the option to download the key to my local storage.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you **already have a key pair** which has the same name as `!Ref NewKeyPair`. You have to ensure that your new key pair has new name, or delete pre-existing key pair.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked.  Do you think creating a keypair through CF is a waste though? Unlike creating it through the console, it does not give me the option to download the key to my local storage. I am unable to use Putty to SSH into it since I do not have it downloaded.

Comment: @user19395568 The key will be available in SSM Parameter Store, where you can download it, and use in putty.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Will look into this.